# Is it better better to open or to read large matrices in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, memory-management, io, julia

I'm in the process of switching over to Julia from other programming languages and one of the things that Julia will let you hang yourself on is memory. I think this is likely a good thing, a programming language where you actually have to think about some amount of memory management forces the coder to write more efficient code. This would be in contrast to something like R where you can seemingly load datasets that are larger than the allocated memory. Of course, you can't actually do that, so I wonder how does R get around that problem?

Part of what I've done in other programming languages is work on large tabular datasets, often converted over to a R dataframe or a matrix. I think the way this is handled in Julia is to stream data in wherever possible, so my main question is this:

Is it better to use `readline("my_file.txt")` to access data or is it better to use `open("my_file.txt", "w")`? If possible, wouldn't it be better to access a large dataset all at once for speed? Or would it be better to always stream data?

I hope this makes sense. Any further resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an extensive user of Julia's data-ecosystem packages, but [CSV.jl offers the `Chunks` and `Rows`](https://csv.juliadata.org/stable/#CSV.Chunks) alternatives to `File`, and these might let you process the files incrementally.

While it may not be relevant to your use case, the mechanisms mentioned in @Przemyslaw Szufel's answer are used other places as well. Two I'm familiar with are the `TiffImages.jl` and `NRRD.jl` packages, both I/O packages mostly for loading image data into Julia. With these, you can load terabyte-sized datasets on a laptop. There may be more packages that use the same mechanism, and many package maintainers would probably be grateful to receive a pull request that supports optional memory-mapping when applicable.

Answer (score 3):

In R you cannot have a data frame larger than memory. There is no magical buffering mechanism. However, when running R-based analytics you could use a [disk.frame](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/disk.frame/) package for that.

Similarly, in Julia if you want to process data frames larger than memory you need to use am appropriate package. The most reasonable and natural option in Julia ecosystem is [JuliaDB](https://juliadb.org/).

If you want to do something more low-level solution have a look at:

- [Mmap](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Mmap/) that provides Memory-mapped I/O that exactly solves the issue of conveniently handling data too large to fit into memory
- [SharedArrays](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/SharedArrays/) that offers a disk mapped array with implementation based on Mmap.

In conclusion, if your data is data frame based - try JuliaDB, otherwise have a look at Mmap and SharedArrays (look at the `filename` parameter)

Comment: A note on JuliaDB. It seems that JuliaDB only supports larger than memory operations if your input data is split into memory appropriate files. There is a quite old issue on this: https://github.com/JuliaData/JuliaDB.jl/issues/127